# How to make `apt install` always ask to continue?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, apt

`dnf install` always asks if I really want to install something but `apt install` will do that only sometimes (usually if the package requires dependencies) but not always. Is there a way to have `apt install` always ask before proceeding so I can double check what it's going to do in case I made a mistake?

Comment: "so I can double check" – There is `--dry-run`; it's not exactly what you're asking for though.

Comment: A short-hand for `--dry-run` is `-s` (for "simulate")